# If $ax^2+bx+c = 0$ and $bx^2+cx + a = 0$ have a common root and $a\neq 0$, then find $\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{abc}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers, quadratics, fractions

If $ax^2+bx+c = 0$ and $bx^2+cx + a = 0$ have a common root and $a\neq 0$, then find $$\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{abc}$$

I tried that for both equations to have a common root, the expression on left hand sides must be equal, ie $$ax^2+bx+c = bx^2+cx + a$$

for this we must have $x=1$ (i cannot prove this, but it appears to be true). Also both of these must be equal to $0$, so we have:

$$a+b+c=0$$

So using this we say 
$$\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{abc} = \frac{a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc+3abc}{abc}=\frac{(a+b+c)(...)}{abc}+3$$

So we get the answer as $3$.

How do we say that $x =1$ is the commmon root? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$0=ax^3+bx^2+cx=ax^3-a$$
which gives $x=1$, $a+b+c=0$ and since $$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc)=0,$$ we obtain:
$$\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{abc}=\frac{3abc}{abc}=3.$$

If you wish the solution for $x\in\mathbb C$ and $\{a,b,c\}\subset\mathbb C$ then since
$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a+\zeta b+\zeta^2c)(a+\zeta^2 b+\zeta c),$$
where $\zeta=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$, we get the same answer.

Comment: nice answer! thanks! So in the first line we get a factor $x^3-1 = (x-1)(x^2+x+1)$. So we rejected the roots of $x^2+x+1$?

Comment: @akhmeteni Yes, of course! But $x^3=1\Leftrightarrow x=1$ is better, I think.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg, How is it better? The $\iff$ is faulty, right? Does it really matter what we wish??

Comment: So can we say the common root of original quadratic is $1$ or not? I just said it to get an answer but is it true?

Comment: @akhmeteni If your problem in $\mathbb R$ then $1$ is an unique common root.

Comment: Sorry but If quadratic is in $C$ then also $1$ should be common root right, as other two would not satisfy!?

Comment: Oh I understand I think they may satisfy! Hm so as lab says we cannot find actual common root here!

Comment: @akhmeteni No! In $\mathbb C$ the common root can be $\zeta$. See please my solution.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Yeah I mean in $C$ it can be $1$ or $\zeta$ or $\zeta^2$ but we don't know which, but all three give the same solution am I correct?

Comment: @akhmeteni It gives the same solution, but if $x\neq1$ then maybe $a+b+c\neq0$, but $(a+\zeta b+\zeta^2c)(a+\zeta^2 b+\zeta c)=0$ because $\zeta^3=1$.

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee It's impossible! See the given.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg, Actually following my method, I reached at $$a(a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc)=0$$ Sorry I didn't notice the condition

Answer (score 2):

We have $$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c\\g(x)=bx^2+cx+a$$

If we set $t$ as the common root, then we know that $f(t)=g(t)=0$:

\begin{align}at^2+bt+c&=bt^2+ct+a\end{align}

We can equate coefficents to conclude that $a=b=c$

Therefore, we can say that \begin{align}\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{abc}&=\frac{a^3+a^3+a^3}{aaa}\\
&=\frac{3a^3}{a^3}\\
&=3\end{align}

Comment: I think your solution is wrong. Try $a=1$, $b=-2$ and $c=1$.

Comment: @lioness99a Which says that your statement $a=b=c$ is wrong!

Comment: We cannot equate coefficients since we only know that they are equal for a single value of t, not for all t.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Let $t$ be the common root

So, we have $$at^2+bt+c=0\  \ \  \ (1)$$ and $$bt^2+ct+a=0\  \ \  \ (2)$$

So, we have two simultaneous equations in $t^2,t$

Solve for $t,t^2$ and use the identity $$t^2=(t)^2$$

Comment: @akhmeteni, We actually don't need to bother about the exact value of the common root as it will be eliminated here.